# jquery file not linking with html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The jquery file doesn't seem to be linking with my html code. The jquery file is suppose to validate the inputs and add the respective glyphicons depending on the validation. I have tried searching for errors, closing tags but can't find any problem. Could anyone please check and point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

```js
//validate.js
function validateText(id) {
  if ($("#" + id).val() == null || $("#" + id).val() == "") {
    var div = $("#" + id).closest("div");
    div.removeClass("has-success");
    $("#glypcn" + id).remove();
    div.addClass("has-error has-feedback");
    div.append('<span id="glypcn' + id + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>');
    return false;
  } else {
    var div = $("#" + id).closest("div");
    div.removeClass("has-error");
    div.addClass("has-success has-feedback");
    $("#glypcn" + id).remove();
    div.append('<span id="glypcn' + id + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>');
    return true;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginbtn2").click(function() {
    if (!validateText("#USN")) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!validateText("#Password2")) {
      return false;
    }
    $("form#students_form").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="/WP Project/image/png" href="/bmsce.png">
  <title>BMS Login Page</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .one:hover {
      color: red;
    }
    .modal-backdrop {
      z-index: -1;
    }
    h4 {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h4 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
            LOGIN
        </h4>
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close one" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <div class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">
            <div align="center">
              <img src="/WP Project/bmsce.png" width="150px" height="150px" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tab" href="#students">Students</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <br />
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="students">
              <div class="well">
                <form role="form" action="" id="students_form" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="USN" id="students_form">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="USN" placeholder="Enter USN" name="username" size=30 aria-describedby="PasswordStatus" />


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password2">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password2" placeholder="Password" name="password" size=30 />


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                  <p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Back</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginbtn2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Sign in</button>
                    <br />
                  </p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="validate.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#modal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: false
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One thing that I notice is you're looking for `$("##USN")` and `$("##Password2")`, adding one hash too many.

Comment: remove `#` from `validateText("#Password2")`

Comment: Try adding the JQuery file in the head not before the doctype declaration

Comment: check path of validate.js in your directory.

Comment: remove script used above doctype

Answer (score 1):

You have included two jQuery versions in the one HTML file. Remove the 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` From above your DocType declaration

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be loading two different versions of jquery in the same page:

```
jquery-2.1.3.min.js
jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
```